# Replace null value between commas nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a string 
str = AI,CO,DO,,,,AD,AD,DE,,DE,FF

I want to replace the space between two commas with a null. I use this string to load into a MS SQL table and the DB keep complaining about a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on the "," and then loop through each element and see if its missing. Then if it is, add your "null" and then join back using "," again.

```js
var str = "AI,CO,DO,,,,AD,AD,DE,,DE,FFF"

var split = str.split(",");
split.forEach(function(str, index) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    split[index] = "null";
  }
});

var joined = split.join(",");
console.log(joined);
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. I was just lookng for a simple replace, but this helps

Comment: @alangilbi no problem, if this ended up solving your question feel free to mark it as accepted.